# "E: The repository does not have a Release file." error when trying to update on Debian 12

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, repository

When trying to do `sudo apt update`, I get faced with:

```
Hit:1 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Ign:2 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-security InRelease
Hit:3 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Err:4 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-security Release
404  Not Found [IP: ***.**.**.*** ***]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I believe the Error is telling you what to do.  The security update server has no release file, and I don't believe you need that anyway, as it is finding Hit #2

Answer (score 1):

You have the following line in your sources.list:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-security main
```

The `/debian` directory doesn't contain the security updates, it should be replaced by:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bookworm-security main
```

Command line:

```
sudo sed -e '/security/s/^/#/' -i /etc/apt/sources.list 
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bookworm-security main" |
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```